# Dataset y actualización o inserción a traves de un datagridview

Tags: dataset

mi pregunta es la siguiente 
Estoy haciendo una aplicación que me conecte con una base de datos por codigo utilizando dataset y que me muestre la tabla de la base de datos en un datagridview ahora bien lo que quiero realizar es que cuando yo ingresé una nueva fila al datagridview también lo haga en la base de datos o cuando modifique una de estas también lo haga en la base de datos utilizando un solo botón "guardar" si me podueden ayudar les agradezco de antemano

Comment: Sin nada más de apoyo es difícil poder contestarte  a la pregunta. Adjunta lo que lleves de código o pruebas así será mas fácil que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: Entiendo Lo que sucede es que solo quiero saber cómo se hace esa parte

Comment: Solo quiero que una tabla de SQL server se cargue en una datagridview y cuando yo modifique o inserte en esa datagridview lo haga en la tabla de la base de datos